# How can I make an onclick handler with a row index as parameter, on a DataView Grid row in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.net dataview grid, and I want that each row should have a function written with onclick property and cursor pointer.

When the file is compiled and then opened in a browser, the rows should look like this:

```
<tr onclick = 'update( 1 )'>
<td>..... </td>

</tr>

<tr onclick = 'update ( 2 )' 
<td>..... </td>

</tr>
```

etc.

Comment: Your question is not clear pls be more descriptive

Comment: code was removed by site, now its clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the `RowDataBound` event of the Gridview.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:alert('Hello');");
        e.Row.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");         
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i change color of the row on which i hover my mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, why cant u write the required functionality in `SelectedIndexChanged()` event of the datagridview? And also you can give set the style of the selected index like this

```
<SelectedItemStyle Font-Size="10px" Font-Names="Verdana" HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="Black" VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="Gold"></SelectedItemStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the tr using e.Row and the index using e.Row.RowIndex in the RowDataBound event. The bound data is accessible using e.Row.DataItem in case you want to access the real Id of the object or the old values.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {            
        var theItem = e.Row.DataItem as MyItemType;
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick","update('" + e.Row.RowIndex + "')");
        e.Row.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer"); 
    }
}
```

Index starts at 0 for the row collection, so in case you want index to start at 1 you need to add 1 to RowIndex.

Comment: Simple and straightforward. Forgot that you can access the row's attributes in the OnRowDataBound event. However, the OP indicated he wants to start his counts at 1, yours will start at 0. You also need to provide the code that will ensure that it is a cursor when the mouse hovers of the Tr.

Answer (score 0):

this onclick event.. is this to point to a custom javascript function? meaning... is `update(1)` a client side javascript function?

I you are looking to perform some server side operation when a row of the datagridview is clicked.. this is the method...

1. add a select command column to the datagridview: This will enable the user to select a row.
2. Write whatever you want done in the onSelectedIndexChanged event handler of the datagridview.

Following is the aspx of the gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." BackColor="White" 
    BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
    ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserId" HeaderText="UserId" 
            SortExpression="UserId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Pay attention to the  in the `columns` tag

Your event handler will be like...

 `protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Write whatever you want here
    }`

Comment: The OP wanted to be able to update the row using client script when clicking anywhere on the row. You're altering the UI by adding a button and perform the update on the server side.

Comment: @PHeiberg The question reads "How can i made onclick with row index as parameter, on DataView Grid row in asp.net?"... the description does not at any point imply that it is client side solution that is being looked at... That is why I have mentioned that this is a solution for the LATTER tranlation. This code however DOES get converted to javascript.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something fundamental, the only javascript code that your solution will emit is the one generated for the update button by ASP.NET, but that will not call the OP's update script. In short, the OP wants client side execution, this answer provides server side execution.

Comment: @PHeiberg - I agree with the fact that this answer provides server side execution. It does explicitly state that. But it is not correct to say that the OP's question implied, let alone clearly stated that it was a client side execution which did not call on server side functionality. Which is what this answer actually does. Client side script generated handles the UI update of highlighting the correct row, while a post back occurs to perform whatever logical operation.

Comment: Ok, granted. The question isn't that clear. I based my assumptions on the OP's expected output.