# How to prevent postback on gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, postback, edit, autopostback

I have a gridview which causes postback when I want to edit a row by clicking on the "edit" in my gridview.

How can I prevent postback upon editing?

Answer (score 1):

```
use Ajax Update Panel Control, Sample code.. this may helpful to you..


 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="grdUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:GridView ID="grdItemDetails" runat="server">
         -- your code --
         -- your code --
         -- your code --
      </asp:gridView>
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:updatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that In each row you have a edit button. On clicking the edit button you can populate the controls or your **Data Entry Form** without the postback. example [**RowBoundEvent**](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=rowboundevent%20client%20event%20add&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CEAQFjAC&url=http://forums.asp.net/t/1116155.aspx/1&ei=UUE2T9nNHsTI0QWuwcW3Ag&usg=AFQjCNEqecXCgiLNsm4IQw1wmV2oi0tjQg&cad=rja) of Gridview.

---

Add the **onclick attributes** on the edit button click in this event.

---

**References**

[**GridView Row Click Selection via ClientSide Code**](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2008/08/04/gridview-row-click-selection-via-clientside-code.aspx)

[**How can i made onclick with row index as parameter, on GridView Grid row in asp.net?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6133728/726802)

[**c# gridview row click**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/331231/726802)

---

Use `Update Panel` to avoid `Postbacks` for the `Gridview events`. Make sure to use `UpdateMode="Conditional"`

---

**References**

[**Remember to set UpdatePanel's UpdateMode to Conditional**](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/05/24/updatemode-default-value-for-the-updatepanel-is-always.aspx)